# Get rid of show String in instance Show for polymorphic type

Tags: haskell

I have a type kinda `data T a = T a`

I want to declare `Show` instance for this type, something like

```
instance Show a => Show (T a) where
  show (T smth) = ... ++ show smth
```

But I don't want to call `show smth` if `a` is `String`, because I don't need additional quotes

Is there any solution how to declare such an instance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You  might consider modifying `T`: `data T a = TStr String | TOther a`. Now your `Show` instance can determine from the argument to `show` whether to use `show` recursively.

Comment: The answer is "basically yes, but you shouldn't". If you have specific demands of your visual representation then `Show` simply isn't the right tool for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to declare an instance of `Show` for `T String` you can use `FlexibleInstances`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data T a = T a

instance Show (T String) where
  show (T smth) = smth
```

You would then need to provide explicit instances for other `a`s that you wish to support.

---

If you want to retain your catch-all instance shown in your question too, you would then be into using `OVERLAPS/OVERLAPPABLE`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data T a = T a

instance {-# OVERLAPPABLE #-} Show a => Show (T a) where
    show (T smth) = show smth

instance {-# OVERLAPPING #-} Show (T String) where
    show (T smth) = smth
```

Comment: You _can_ do that, but overlapping instances are usually a sign that you're abusing type classes for something that better be done in a direct way.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Agreed.  I think more context would really help for suggesting alternatives so thought I'd just suggest a potential way of solving the problem as described.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thank you! Yeah, I know that it's not a good way, and I'm disappointed that I have to use such a "tricks" just for avoiding qoutes

Comment: @NikitaVoloshin perhaps you should explain a bit more for what you're actually trying to accomplish, to get advice on a better alternative.

Comment: @leftaroundabout well, I have a type similar to one described above. And for now, there are only two alternatives for type parameter: either `Int` or `String`. And yes, I know that I can do smth like `data TInt = TInt Int` and `data TString = TString String` and work with them separately. But my question was about the general case.
For example, `list` is an instance like that.

Comment: @NikitaVoloshin Have you considered simply writing separately `instance Show (T Int)` and `instance Show (T String)`? — Anyways, that's not really what I meant: _what do you need `show` on this type for, and why does it matter to have strings wrapped in extra quotes_?

Comment: If you're concerned with presentation, you probably want a pretty printing library, not `Show`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout maybe I'm doing wrong, but `instance Show (T String)` doesn't compile with message `Illegal instance declaration for Show (T String)`. And about quotes: presentation matters, there is a grammar string representation must satisfy

Comment: @Carl thank you for advice, but actually it's not my case because I'm not allowed to use 3rd party libraries for some reasons

Comment: @NikitaVoloshin You need to use `FlexibleInstances` as shown above to create an instance of `Show (T String)` otherwise you will get that error.

Comment: @NikitaVoloshin yeah, it requires `FlexibleInstances`, but unlike `Overlapping` that's completely harmless and uncontroversial.

Comment: AFAIK, it's better to use OVERLAPPING instead of OVERLAPS, for the latter also implies OVERLAPPABLE.

Comment: So, guys, thank you all for your answers! It's really helpful